# Is there a way to print an arraylist in groups?

Tags: java, printing, arraylist

```
for(int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
    System.out.print(arrayList.get(j));
}
```

I would like to print in groups of 5, but how would the code look? Do i have to store the elements into a variable and print them that way?

Comment: When you say "groups of 5", what do you mean?  Do you mean 5 elements per line?  one element per line, and a break after every 5 lines?  Also, what have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 7):

How about adding a simple line break after each 5 elements?

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++){
   System.out.print(arrayList.get(j) + " ");
   if (j % 5 == 4) {
       System.out.print("\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Although `j%5==4` might be better, so that it doesn't start with `\n`

Comment: Short, concise, accurate.  +1.

Comment: may I suggest, `System.out.print(arrayList.get(j) + ((j % 5 == 4)?  "\n" : " "));`

Comment: @nachokk: when using `Iterator` for a for each loop you don't have a loop counter you can check. This would require adding another variable.

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly. I put them in a line so it separates in groups of 5 on one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j+=5){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
         //Inside this loop you can do whatever you want, concatenate...
         System.out.print(arrayList.get(i+j));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) to break them.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++){
    if ((j != 0) && (j % 4 == 0) { System.out.println(""); }
    System.out.print(arrayList.get(j));
}
```

Oops... Just realized lots of people answered this already...